# Pymongo Query Filtering a versioned data

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Here's a sample data from my database:

```
  {'data': 
     [{'is_active': True, 'printer_name': 'A', 'vid': 14510}, 
      {'is_active': True, 'printer_name': 'Changed A', 'vid': 14511}
     ]
  }, 
  {'data': 
    [{'is_active': False, 'printer_name': 'B', 'vid': 14512}]
  }
```

The `vid` field here is the `version id`. Whenever a record is edited, the modified data is pushed into the list and it therefore has a higher vid than its old version.

Now I want to define a method called `get_all_active_printers` which returns all printers with `is_active :True`

Here's my attempt, but it returns both printers when it should not return printer `B`

```
def get_all_active_printers():
    return printers.find(
        {'data.is_active':  True}, {"data": {"$slice": -1}, '_id': 0, 'vid': 0})
```

Whats wrong with my query ?

***Edit 1 in response to comment by WanBachtiar***

Here's the actual output from using the command `print([c for c in get_all_active_printers()])`

```
[{'data': [{'printer_name': 'Changed A', 'vid': 1451906336.6602068, 'is_active': True, 'user_id': ObjectId('566bbf0d680fdc1ac922be4c')}]}, {'data': [{'printer_name': 'B', 'vid': 1451906343.8941162, 'is_active': False, 'user_id': ObjectId('566bbf0d680fdc1ac922be4c')}]}]
```

As you can see in the actual output - the `is_active` value for Printer `B` is False, but `get_all_active_printers` still returns `B`

Here's my version details:

- Python 3.4.3
- pymongo 3.2
- mongodb 2.4.9

On Ubuntu 14.04, if that matters.

***Edit 2***

Noticed yet another issue. The query is returning `vid` field, even though have clearly mentioned `'vid': 0` in the projection.

*** Edit 3***

I am not sure by what you mean when you say

> "make sure that there is no other documents for {'printer_name': 'B'}"

. Yes the second data (on printer B) has a second row. That was the first data - when the printer was created when the field `is_active` was `true`. Later it becomes `false`. Here's the snapshot of the database:

[image]

But I want to filter on the latest data as old data is only for keeping an audit trail.

If i move `'data.is_active': True` to the projections as in the following code:

```
def get_all_active_printers():
    return printers.find(
        {}, {'data': {'$slice': -1}, 'data.is_active': True, '_id': 0, 'vid': 0})
```

I get the following error message:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: You cannot currently
>   mix including and excluding fields. Contact us if this is an issue.

So how do i filter based on the latest data, given the snapshot above ?  Sorry if my question did not make it clear earlier.

Comment: I did a quick test with your example data in Python 2.7,  PyMongo 3.2 and the same query returns only A. Which Python and PyMongo versions are you using ?  Does the example dataset from Python print out ? cheers.

Comment: @WanBachtiar - Thanks a lot. I have updated the question with details of version and the output from the python print statement. Please see if you can find anything wrong

Comment: Do you have multiple documents at data subdocument at the second document ?

Comment: @MaDeRkAn, this particular example has one document for second printer, but in case the  data for it is modified in future, the new document is pushed to the second item and so on. This is to keep an audit trail of whatever changes happen to a document.

Comment: Can you please make sure that there is no other documents for {'printer_name': 'B'} ? As $slice removes the first array element and may remove the element matching the query. You can confirm by removing "data": {"$slice": -1}. Cheers.

Comment: @WanBachtiar: I have updated my answer under the section edit 3

Comment: First use $unwind then use 'data.is_active': True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying the question.
So you are wanting to query documents that have only the latest element with `is_active: True`.

Unfortunately, in your case `find({'data.is_active': True})` would find all documents containing any `data` element with `is_active:True`, not just the last element in the array. Also, without knowing the length of the array, you cannot reference the last element of the array using the `array.i` syntax.

However there are other ways/alternatives:

1. Update using [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push), [$each](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#each) and [$position](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#position) to insert new elements to the front of the array. [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/) example:

```js
/* When updating */
db.printers.update(
    /* Filter document for printer B */
    {"data.printer_name": 'B'}, 
    /* Push a new document to the front of the array */
    {"$push": { 
            "data": { 
                $each: [{'is_active': false, 'printer_name': "B", 'vid': 14513 }],
                $position: 0 
            } 
        } 
    }
);

/* When querying now you know that the latest one is on index 0 */
db.printers.find(
    {"data.0.is_active": true},
    {"data": { $slice: 1} }
);
```

Note that $position is new in MongoDB v2.6.

2. Use MongoDB [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array, [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) then [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter. For example:

```js
db.printers.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$data' }, 
    {$sort: { 'data.vid' : 1 } }, 
    {$group: {
        '_id': { 'printer_name' : '$data.printer_name', id:'$_id' },
        'vid': { $max: '$data.vid' }, 
        'is_active' : { $last: '$data.is_active' } 
        } 
    }, 
    {$match:{"is_active": true}}
]);
```

It may be beneficial for you to re-consider the document schema. For example, instead of having an array of documents maybe you should consider having them flat for ease of querying.

```js
{'is_active': true, 'printer_name': 'A', 'vid': 14512} 
{'is_active': false, 'printer_name': 'B', 'vid': 14513}
```

For more examples and discussions of different version tracking schema designs, see these blog posts:

- [How to track versions with MongoDB](http://www.askasya.com/post/trackversions/)
- [Further thought on how to track versions with MongoDB](http://www.askasya.com/post/revisitversions/)

Also a useful reference on schema designs : [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

> The query is returning vid field, even though have clearly mentioned
>   'vid': 0 in the projection.

You could hide it with `"data.vid": 0` instead of `vid:0`.

> If i move 'data.is_active': True to the projections as in the following code... I get the following error message.

There are rules of projections that you have to follow. Please see [projecting fields from query results](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) for more information on projections.

If you are starting a new project, I would recommend to use the latest stable release of MongoDB, currently it is [v3.2.0](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production).

Regards,

Wan.

Comment: thanks for such a comprehensive answer and for being with me all the way through it :)